# How to upload an image to S3 bucket using REST API in Android, Getting Forbidden Error: 403

Tags: android, amazon-s3, file-upload, bucket

I want to upload media data to S3 bucket using REST API without using the Amazon SDK. I am getting “403 Forbidden Access Denied Error” on file upload to s3 bucket, please suggest suitable actions. If anything else is required I can share that too.

```
String bucket = getString(R.string.s3_bucket);
            RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

            AwsS3 aws = builder.build().create(AwsS3.class);

            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z").withLocale(Locale.US);
            String ZONE = "GMT";
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            DateTime dateTime = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(ZONE)).plusHours(1);
            String formattedDate = dateTime.toString(fmt);

            try {
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                TypedInput body = new TypedByteArray("image/jpg", b);
                String imageName = "files_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
                String oauth = AWSOauth.getOAuthAWS(getApplicationContext(), imageName.trim());
                String host = bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com";
                String mimeType = body.mimeType();
                long length = body.length();
                File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                RequestBody bb = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);

                aws.upload(imageName.trim(),length,"/**",host,formattedDate,mimeType,oauth,bb,new Callback<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void success(String s, Response response) {
                        Log.d("tag","S = " + s);
                        Log.d("tag","getHeaders = " + response.getHeaders());
                        Log.d("tag","Status = " + response.getStatus());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.d("tag","error: S = " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){

            }


 @PUT("/{Key}")
void upload(@Path("Key") String Key,
                    @Header("Content-Length") long length,
                    @Header("Accept") String accept,
                    @Header("Host") String host,
                    @Header("Date") String date,
                    @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                    @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                    @Body RequestBody body,Callback<String> mCallback);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If your app has a backend service associated you can make uploads to S3 without Amazon SDK in the Android app if you get the presigned urls for the uploads generated in your backend and deliver it to the app through an API call. Here is some documentation of Amazon for different languages: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Here is some example of the Android code using the pre signed urls from the backend:

```
public interface AmazonService {
    @Multipart
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Url String url, @PartMap Map<String,RequestBody> params, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}

public class AmazonS3Client {
    private static final String EMPTY_URL_TO_MAKE_RETROFIT_HAPPY = "";

    public boolean uploadMoment(Map<String, String> fields, String filePath, String s3BaseUrl) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(okClient).baseUrl(s3BaseUrl + "/").build();

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), new File(filePath));
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fields.get("key"), requestFile);
        Map<String, RequestBody> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
            parameters.put(entry.getKey(), createPartFromString(entry.getValue()));
        }

        AmazonService service = retrofit.create(AmazonService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(EMPTY_URL_TO_MAKE_RETROFIT_HAPPY, parameters, body);
        try {
            Response<ResponseBody> execute = call.execute();
            if (execute.code() == 204) {
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.e("AmazonS3Client", "unexpected http response: " + execute.code());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("AmazonS3Client", "upload error", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
        return RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more details on this.

Comment: Sorry, I can not provide you with a fully programmed solution, but I added an link for AWS documentation of presigned urls to implement it in your backend and an example of a class I use to make the call in the Android client with Retrofit with the given values from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
*<add this line>>>>>*.setRequestInterceptor(new AuthToken())
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));
```

and your AuthToken will be like :-

```
public class AuthToken implements RequestInterceptor
    {
            @Override
            public void apply(RequestFacade request)
        {
            var authTokenString = AWS <Name>:<Key>
            request.addHeader("Authorization", authTokenString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: String oauth = AWSOauth.getOAuthAWS(getApplicationContext(), imageName.trim());
                    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                            .setEndpoint("http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com")
                            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                            .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthToken(oauth))
                            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

Comment: public class AuthToken implements RequestInterceptor {
        String oauth;
        public AuthToken(String oauth) {
            this.oauth = oauth;
        }
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            // authTokenString = AWS <Name>:<Key>
            request.addHeader("Authorization", oauth);
        }
     }  
I got the error  retrofit.RetrofitError: 501 Not Implemented